# How to loop through dataframe column and compare dates to current

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe containing a date column I would like to loop through these dates and compare it to the current date to see if any entry is today. I tried converting the column to a list using the tolist() method but it outputted not the date but rather "Timestamp('2022-08-02 00:00:00')" however my column only contains dates formatted as %Y-%m-%d as you can see in the image.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llwxR.png)

Comment: A common pandas theme is that you don't iterate over cells in a column one by one, instead you apply an operation to the entire column. It's (sometimes much) faster that way.

Comment: It's always better to place your data in the question itself (either code to remake it or at least a table in markdown format). Linking to an image of your data is not ideal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Dataframe is called df, here's a possible way of solving your issue:

```
df.loc[df.Date == pd.Timestamp.now().date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
```

I think it's a straightforward solution, you filter your dataframe by "Date" and compare to the date part of "today's date" while maintaining the correct format of y-m-d.